# A JNI error has occured

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I built a GUI form through Intellij. I exported the app as an artifact to a JAR file. I opened the JAR on my personal computer and had no issues - the app appeared and fully functioned. I tried running it on someone else's computer, and when I clicked on the JAR file it said "Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again." After that box, it said "A Java Exception has occurred." I tried this on my laptop, and the JAR file properly opened.

I think it has to do with the JRE or JDK being necessary on a computer, but I do not know enough about Java to fix my problem. The computers I tried that it didn't work on either had JDK installed or not installed at all.

Suggestions?

Edit - I'm using Java 10. The other computer that it didn't work on had Java 8. I ran jar on the command, and the error is here - [stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQMMo.png)
I guess the solution is update java? but then is there a way to force java 10 code to run on a java 8 computer?

Comment: What was the exception?  What version are you running locally such that it works?  What versions of Java were running such that it didn't work?

Comment: You have to build the code for Java8 or earlier in order to run it on Java8. It may be possible to adjust in project settings (I am not familiar with IntelliJ), and it is also possible to do in a command-line build (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/javac.htm, 'source', 'target' and 'release' arguments)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to change the compiler on my app, and then, rebuild the artifact.

Change compiler: File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler